# Session in php for android mobile application

Tags: php

I would like to display the selection of item selected by customer in their own account. I use session_start from login page until display page. but in display page do not show anything after i use session. Before i havent start use session, all item selected by all customer will display together, i heard session can used to display the item selected by specific customer in his account but after use session, it do not show anything. This is mobile android application. It developed by android studio, but the database is using localhost and php. I will post my login, select and display page and also output of display page in here. If anyone knows the answer, please help me modified my code, thanks.

Login php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php 

require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';

$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
if(isset($_POST['user_login']) and isset($_POST['user_pass'])){
    $db = new DbOperations(); 

    if($db->userLogin($_POST['user_login'], $_POST['user_pass'])){
        $user = $db->getUserByUsername($_POST['user_login']);
        $response['error'] = false; 
        $response['ID'] = $user['ID'];
        $response['user_email'] = $user['user_email'];
        $response['user_login'] = $user['user_login'];
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user['user_login'];


    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "Invalid username or password";          
    }

}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
}
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Select Page:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

//Getting values
$username = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
//Creating an sql query
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (username, name, date) VALUES ('$username','$name', '$date')";

//Importing our db connection script
 require_once('dbConnect.php');

//Executing query to database
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

     echo 'Select Successfully';
 }else{
 echo 'Sorry, You Are Select This Item Before';
 }

 //Closing the database 
 mysqli_close($con);
 }
 ?>
```

Display Page:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php 
//Importing Database Script 
require_once('dbConnect.php');

//Creating sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";

//getting result 
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//creating a blank array 
$result = array();

//looping through all the records fetched
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

//Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
array_push($result,array(
"id"=>$row['id'],
"username"=>$row['username'],
"name"=>$row['name'],
"date"=>$row['date']
));
}

//Displaying the array in json format 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```

Display Page Output:

```
{"result":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are connecting Android App to your API server. It initiates [stateless connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol). Session will not work here. At the time of login if the credentials are valid you should create an authentication token and your android app should send this token each time its requesting a resource of webservice. You will need to verify this token on HTTP Server for authenticity.

Consider reading following topics:

[RESTful API Authentication Basics](https://dzone.com/articles/restful-api-authentication-basics-1)

[RESTFul API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

Hope this helps.